# Error when I tried to use the blup function (package "pedigree")

Tags: r

I'm trying to make a BLUP. I have the pedigree data and the production data, so I'm trying to make a BLUP with this to perform the genetic evaluation of the animals and choose the best.

When I tried to use the function "blup" (from the package pedigree), it showed me a error:

> Error in LU.dgC(a) : cs_lu(A) failed: near-singular A (or out of memory)

but I don't understand what that means.